# Access array inside an object return Illegal string offset warning

Tags: php, arrays, object

This is part of my object stored in `$book` variable

```
stdClass (object) [Object ID #59][3 properties]
    discurso_trecho_candidato: 
        stdClass (object) [Object ID #58][24 properties]
            ...
        discurso_trecho_tema: 
            (array) [2 elements]
                0: 
                stdClass (object) [Object ID #60][10 properties]
                    term_id: (integer) 15 
                    ...
                1: 
                stdClass (object) [Object ID #61][10 properties]
                    term_id: (integer) 13 
                    ...
        discurso_trecho: (string) <p>trcheo sobre desemprego e economia</p>
```

When I try to store `discurso_trecho_tema` array in a variable:

```
$trecho_temas = $book['discurso_trecho_tema'];
```

Page return this warning:

> Warning: Warning: Illegal string offset 'discurso_trecho_tema' in ... string(1) "<"

Comment: when we access any object we need to use arrow -> please check by use arrow :p

Comment: @Sourabh `discurso_trecho_tema` is an array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$trecho_temas = $book->discurso_trecho_candidato->discurso_trecho_tema;
```

So `$trecho_temas` should have the array.

Comment: This return Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: $book represent discurso_trecho_candidato object